# How to make image width with dialog width using dialog fragment in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Can anybody tell me how to make image width with dialog width using dialog fragment in android?

I have tried using the code below, but it is not working in android 2.3:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical"
    >
     <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:src="@drawable/performance_nophoto" 
        android:id="@+id/imgPerformance"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        /> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use **android:background="@drawable/performance_nophoto"**  instead of **android:src="@drawable/performance_nophoto"**

Comment: No @visheshchandra, setting the image as `android:src` is fine . If you change it to `android:background` then the `ImageView ` won't work properly.

Comment: please reomve this android:adjustViewBounds="true" properties from "ImageView"

Comment: @Haresh still it is not working

Answer (score 0):

first of all if you set android:adjustViewBounds="true" in imageview then scaletype property of imageview not working
so,you have to use either android:adjustViewBounds="true" or  android:scaleType="fitXY".

For your problem,simply remove android:adjustViewBounds="true" from imageview